# Changing Base value layout for iphone, affects ipad layout

Tags: ios, size-classes, ios-autolayout, xcode7.3, ios9.3

I have a layout with size class width any, height any which is currently working for iPad landscape. I have a task to design same layout for iPhone portrait.

When I started designing with size class of compact width ,regular height my base layout (any,any) also gets changed.

I am designing this using a storyboard.

**Note** : Please note - upload preview shows properly, but changes when I run on the simulator.

Answer (score 7):

You could create constraints specific to a certain size class in the size inspector. Also if you can give samples of what you want to achieve on the iPhone and iPad, I can give more concrete examples of the constraints.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture what device is being used and then change the constraint programatically. You can use the code below in order to capture what kind of device you are using.

[image: Device Properties]